Trying to make scroll buttons work on their corrispective containers
I'm trying to make 2 buttons for a scroll left and scroll right while working on a Netflix copy, as you can imagine i'm just learning. I'm working on my project with VueJs, i made my btns work but they only work on the movie list while the rest of the btn does nothing, i'm missing something for sure but i still didn't find a solution:
<Template>
<!-- this is our film container -->
    <div id="movieCards" class="container pt-5 pb-5" v-if="store.movie.length > 0">
            <div>
                <h2>
                    Film
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div ref="movieScrollContainer" class="dflex">
                <div class="ls-col" v-for="movie in store.movie" :key="movie.id">
                    <CardComponent :img="store.ImageUrl + movie.poster_path" :name="movie.title" :originalName="movie.original_title" :language="movie.original_language" :vote="movie.vote_average" :overview="movie.overview"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between ">

                <button id="scrollLeftMovie" @click="scroll(-600, 'movieScrollContainer')">
                 scroll left
                </button>

                <button id="scrollRightMovie" @click="scroll(600, 'movieScrollContainer')">
                 scroll right
                </button>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- this is our tvseries container -->
    <div ref="tvScrollContainer" id="tvCards" class="container pt-5 pb-5" v-if="store.movie.length > 0">
            <div>
                <h2>
                    Serie TV
                </h2>
            </div>
        <div class="dflex">
            <div class="ls-col" v-for="series in store.tv" :key="series.id">
                <CardComponent :img="store.ImageUrl + series.poster_path" :name="series.name" :originalName="series.original_name" :language="series.original_language" :vote="series.vote_average" :overview="series.overview"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <button id="scrollLeftTv" @click="scroll(-600, 'tvScrollContainer')">
                scroll left
            </button>

            <button id="scrollRightTv" @click="scroll(600, 'tvScrollContainer')">
                scroll right
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>
</Template>

i triyed to give a 2nd parameter to the function but it seems i'm doing it wrong. Function here:
<script>
import { store } from '../store';
import CardComponent from './CardComponent.vue';
    export default {
        name: 'CardList',
        components: {
            CardComponent
        },
        data() {
            return {
                store
            }
        },
        methods: {
           scroll(distance, id) {
            this.$refs[id].scrollBy({
                left: distance,
                behavior: 'smooth'
            })
           }
        }
    }
</script>

Can someone help me understand what is missing?

SOLVED: i just made a simple mistake by giving the ref=' ' to the wrong containers
